# remove a duplicate record of the same date but add the type to the one that is not removed

Tags: sas

```
DATA table1;
infile datalines DELIMITER=','; 
INFORMAT id 2. type $10. date date2 MMDDYY10. ; 
INPUT id  date type date2;
format date date9.
   date2 date9.;
DATALINES;
1,02/09/2012,BIG,02/09/2012
2,05/16/2012,BIG,05/18/2012
2,06/18/2012,BIG,06/18/2012
2,06/18/2012,SMALL, 
3,08/08/2011,BIG,08/08/2012
3,09/13/2011,BIG,09/13/2012
4,06/08/2016,BIG,06/12/2016
4,06/10/2016,SMALL, 
5,08/16/2012,BIG,08/16/2012
5,08/15/2012,SMALL, 
;
run;

 /*removing same date for an id with different type- only the record with 
 SMALL is REMOVED*/
proc sql;
create table comb as
Select id, date, type,date2 from table1 t
Where type <> "SMALL" or 
not exists(select date from table1 
    where id = t.id and date = t.date and type <> "SMALL");
 run;
```

[image: ![enter image description here]
this removed the record that I want (2 06/18/2012 SMALL )but I want is either the type should indicate BIG & SMALL for the non deleted record or a new field which indicates BIG & SMALL
[image]
Note that only record with small type is deleted when there is duplication for same day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some logic to collapse the multiple values, both for TYPE and for DATE2.

You could use a data step.

```
data want ;
  do until (last.date);
    set have ;
    by id date ;
    length newtype $25 newdate2 8;
    newtype=catx(' ',newtype,type);
    newdate2 = coalesce(date2,newdate2);
  end;
  date2=newdate2;
  drop newdate2;
run;
```

If you really want to stick to SQL (and there are only two values for TYPE) then you could convert your query to a join instead.

```
proc sql noprint;
create table want2 as
select
  coalesce(a.id,b.id) as id
 ,coalesce(a.date,b.date) as date format=date9.
 ,catx(' ',a.type,b.type) as NEWTYPE
 ,coalesce(a.date2,b.date2) as date2 format=date9.
from 
 (select * from have where type='BIG') a
full join
 (select * from have where type='SMALL') b
on a.id = b.id and a.date=b.date
;
quit;
```

P.S. Be careful using `<>` as an operator.  It has a totally different meaning in normal SAS code than it does in SQL code and WHERE statements.

Comment: When I run the datastep of your query it is removing the BIG type when there is duplicate but I want only SMALL type record to be removed if  for id there is a same day record. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you want to keep duplicate records when they are both TYPE='BIG' or do you just want to avoid NEWTYPE='BIG BIG' ?

Comment: yes I want to avoid BIG BIG as this ocurred due to the date2 being different. Is it a small fix if I need to remove small record when the date is between date and date2 of BIG record. I used to change before date = t.date to this t.date BETWEEN date and date2 ?

Comment: You could include TYPE in the BY statement and only execute the catx() when it is first.type.

Comment: i tried this 
PROC SORT DATA= table1;
 BY ID DATE DESCENDING TYPE  ;
RUN;
data want ;
  do until (last.date);
    set table1 ;
    by id date type ;
    length newtype $25 newdate 8;
   if type=first.type then newtype=catx('&',newtype,type);
    newdate = coalesce(date,newdate);
  end;
  date=newdate;
  drop newdate;
run;          #  ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set WORK.TABLE1

Comment: Make your BY statements match.  FIRST. and LAST. variables are binary flags, not actual values.

Comment: have a similiar kind of question but little different it is in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286498/concatenate-the-type-to-the-corresponding-record-before-removing-the-records